# Controller to place opportunity products related list on case page layout

Tags: apex, controller

I am trying to create a controller to view opportunity line items on a case that is related to an opportunity. 
I am not a developer, and copying and pasting code. 
I am currently receiving an error: Error: Compile Error: Invalid field Npe01__Contact_Id_for_Role__c for SObject Opportunity at line 18 column 12
However I see this field mentioned in many samples. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Public With Sharing Class crossObjectOpportunityInfo {
Public Opportunity o                {get; private set;}
Public Case              c              {get; private set;}

Public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
    return SObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.FieldSets.Display_On_Case.getFields();
}

Public crossObjectOpportunityInfo(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
    this.o = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE RELATED_OPPORTUNITY__C = :sc.getId() LIMIT 1];

    String queryString = 'SELECT Id';
    List<Schema.FieldSetMember> querySet = SObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.FieldSets.Display_On_Case.getFields();
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : querySet) {
        queryString += ', '+ f.getFieldPath();
    }

    if(o.Npe01__Contact_Id_for_Role__c == null) {
        Id cid = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :o.AccountId LIMIT 1].Id;
        queryString += ' FROM Opportunity WHERE id = \''+ cid +'\' LIMIT 1';
    }   


    this.contact = database.Query(queryString);  //added comment so code can be formatted
}

}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you have the Salesforce Foundation Nonprofit Starter Pack installed. The field that is throwing you compile error is a field that exists in the Households package. Please go to Setup > Installed Packages to confirm.

Comment: @greenstork I do not have the Nonprofit Starter Pack installed. Do you know how I could do this with the starter pack?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code you borrowed is from someone who is using the Nonprofit Starter Pack since any field with the namespace npe01__ comes from the Households package of the NPSP.  Try removing this line from your code:

```
if(o.Npe01__Contact_Id_for_Role__c == null) {
```

and the corresponding close bracket below it to at least allow your class to compile.

Comment: Thank you, I then receive the error: Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: contact at line 24 column 9 
        this.contact = database.Query(queryString);

Comment: I have deleted that and it will now save. I will do some testing. Thank you for your help